# Apply and OK Button in Eclipse PreferencePage

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, preference

What is the standard and recommended way the apply and ok button in eclipse preference page should work.

I checked and found that performOK() method is called when we click apply or ok button. It means if I have some computations or let say thread starting on in performOK() and the user first click on apply and then ok button it will be executed twice and if the user clicks on apply and cancel the changes will be applied anyways?

Is there a way to not execute the code twice if the user clicks on apply and then ok ?

```
@Override
protected void performApply() {
    this.performOk();
}

@Override
public boolean performOk() {
    PreferencesUtil.savePreferences();
    return super.performOk();
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is up to you to remember that Apply has been run by overriding `performApply` and setting a flag. You can then test the flag in `performOk` and skip doing the same thing.

Be sure to clear the flag if the user changes something after pressing Apply.

So something like:

```
private boolean saveDone = false;


public boolean performOk() {

  if (!saveDone) {
    saveDone = true;

    store.setValue(Constants.ENABLE_DEFAULT_COLOR, this.defaultColoringCheckBox.getSelection());
    PreferencesUtil.addToPreferenceStore(viewer.getTable());
    PreferencesUtil.savePreferences();
  }

  return super.performOk();
}
```

Set `saveDone = false` if anything is changed in the page.

Comment: Should I write my implementation in performApply or performOK?

Comment: performApply normally just calls performOk.

Comment: in this case if the user clicks apply and then ok the performOk will be executed twice

Comment: As I already said set a flag to remember that you have run the code.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would make sense to extract the functionality to be executed while the user wishes to apply the changes in a separate method. This method is called from apply AND ok.
I would not call "performOK" from within "performApply". In performOk the additional closing of the preferences Dialog is then performed by the super method, I suppose.